# Display store and read Date from Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

In my App an important function is to save Dates to a SQLite database. What is the correct way to store a Date Object from Java in a database? And what is the best way to read into a Date Object from the datbase? And do I have to use the *util* or the *sql* (from the namespace) Date?

Also the app should be published in all countries from the play store so I want to show the date in the correct location string. If I want to display a String in a TextView like this:

```
Freitag, 06.03.2012      // Germany
Friday,  03.06.2012      // US (don't know if this is correct for US)

// The 0 befor one numbers is important for me
```

Is there a way in Android to create a DateString like above in the current location, which is set in the settings? I want to use as little deprecated methodes as possible.

Comment: It's usually easiest to just store the unix timestamp in the database, and then format it however you like when rendering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SQLite Date and Time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> 1)YYYY-MM-DD

So you should insert date in database using that format.
When you want to show a date in android you can query the database (getting a row in the format YYYY-MM-DD).

After that you can format that value in the way you want. For example if you want `Friday, 03.06.2012` you can do this way:

```
try {
    String dateString = "2013-05-07";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
    Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateString);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US);
    String result = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now in `result` you have `Tuesday, 07.05.2013`. If you change locale to `Locale.GERMAN` you get `Dienstag, 07.05.2013`.

Comment: great thank you that works wunderful. If I want to put out the correct DateString for the current location is there a way to get the current location from Android for the second argument of `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: Yes, you can use [Locale.getDefault()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()) which allows you to know what is the user's preferred locale.